# Convert pandas.DataFrame to numpy tensor using factor levels for shape

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensor, numpy-ndarray

I have data from a full factorial experiment.  For example, for each of `N` samples, I have `J` types of measurement and `K` measurement loci.  I receive this data in long format, for example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import itertools
from numpy.random import normal as rnorm

# [[N], [J], [K]]
levels = [[1,2,3,4], ['start', 'stop'], ['gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3']]

# fully crossed
exp_design = list(itertools.product(*levels))

df = pd.DataFrame(exp_design, columns=["sample", "mode", "gene"])

# some fake data
df['x'] = rnorm(size=len(exp_design))
```

which results in 24 observations (`x`) with a column for each of the three factors.

```
> df.head()
    sample  mode    gene    x
0   1       start   gene1   -1.229370
1   1       start   gene2   1.129773
2   1       start   gene3   -1.155202
3   1       stop    gene1   -0.757551
4   1       stop    gene2   -0.166129
```

I want to convert these observations to the corresponding `(N,J,K)`-shaped tensor (numpy array).  I was thinking pivoting to wide format with a MultiIndex, then extracting values would generate the correct tensor, but it simply comes off as a column vector:

```
> df.pivot_table(values='x', index=['sample', 'mode', 'gene']).values
array([[-1.22936989],
       [ 1.12977346],
       [-1.15520216],
       ...,
       [-0.1031641 ],
       [ 1.1296491 ],
       [ 1.31113584]])
```

**Is there a quick way to get tensor formatted data from a long format `pandas.DataFrame`?**

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
df.agg('nunique')

Out[69]: 
sample     4
mode       2
gene       3
x         24
dtype: int64
s=df.agg('nunique')
df.x.values.reshape(s['sample'],s['mode'],s['gene'])
Out[71]: 
array([[[-2.78133759e-01, -1.42234420e+00,  5.42439121e-01],
        [ 2.15359867e+00,  6.55837886e-01, -1.01293568e+00]],
       [[ 7.92306679e-01, -1.62539763e-01, -6.13120335e-01],
        [-2.91567999e-01, -4.01257702e-01,  7.96422763e-01]],
       [[ 1.05088264e-01, -7.23400925e-02,  2.78515041e-01],
        [ 2.63088568e-01,  1.47477886e+00, -2.10735619e+00]],
       [[-1.71756374e+00,  6.12224005e-04, -3.11562798e-02],
        [ 5.26028807e-01, -1.18502045e+00,  1.88633760e+00]]])
```

Comment: I think it's important to note here that this assumes that data frame is first sorted like, `df.sort_values(by=['sample', 'mode', 'gene'])`

Comment: @merv yes you are right